# How can I see a specific page's memory consumption of a browser?

Tags: browser, memory-management, profiler

What way or which profiler tool I should use to see a specific web page's memory consumption?

Does it make a difference if it belongs to a TAB in an individual browser window?

Thanks

Comment: not a dupe, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page/

Answer (score 1):

In chrome every tab is a separate process, so there you can just compare the memory consumption of an empty tab against the memory consumption of a tab loaded with the page in question.

For other browsers this does not work of course. IE9 will have tabs in seperate process too I think though.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser is going to be different.

Google Chrome, for instance, has a Task Manager, <kbd>SHIFT+ESC</kbd>, that will itemize each tab, and each tab is actually a separate process in Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only Chrome supports this directly. Open a tab to `about:memory` and you can see the memory usage of each tab.