# calculating memory usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, sorting, memory

I have written a program in Javascript which reads numbers from a file ,sorts them and then writes them back to the file.But I not able able to find a suitable method or tool to get the memory usage of the program.(something like Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(); in java).If someone could please give me a lead I would be thankful.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
<script>
var oRequest;

var data=new Array();
var b= new Array();
var j
var k;
var temp;
var temp1;

if(document.all) {

oRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
else {

oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}


oRequest.open("GET", "file:///C:/numbers.txt", true);
oRequest.send(null);


numbers= oRequest.responseText.split("\n");
for (var i = 0;i<(numbers.length-1);i++)
{
numbers[i] = parseInt(numbers[i],10);
}

var d = new Date();
var start = d.getTime();

for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<(numbers.length-1);j++)
{
 if(numbers[j]>numbers[j+1])
{
 temp=numbers[j+1];
  numbers[j+1] = numbers[j];
  numbers[j] = temp;
 }
 }}

var g = new Date();
var end =g.getTime();
var diff=(end-start);


</script>
<script>
function WriteFile() 
{
var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\BubbleJS.txt", true); 
for(i=0;i<5000;i++)
{
fh.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}   
fh.WriteLine("\n");
fh.WriteLine("The time required for sorting is "+diff+" Milliseconds");
fh.Close(); 
}
 </script>


<form>
<body background="Bubble.png">
 <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
 <input type="button" onClick='alert("Directing to Home Page"); window.location = "Home           Page.html"' value="Back to Home  Page">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" onClick=WriteFile(); value="Begin Sorting!" 
    style="width: 174px; margin-left: 0px">&nbsp;&nbsp;

   </form>

   </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery or javascript to find memory usage of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript language and core libraries do not provide a way to view or calculate the memory usage of the runtime.

Your only hope is to find a library (e.g. ActiveX plugin, etc.) which can do it for you.  Note that the developer tools of some popular web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, possibly others) provide a memory profiling graphical interface, so perhaps there are programmatic hooks you can find; however, if they exist they almost definitely won't work cross-browser.