# find free memory available in client machine using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory

We have a requirement to find the free RAM memory available on a client machine only in IE based on free memory we have to execute some processing or pause current running processing.

I found same is there in Java, but java give information about server system not machine where browser open.

Comment: You can't really get more info than what the Browser is giving you. So you could only get the free memory of the browser itself not the whole CPU. There is the  `window.performance.memory` function that gives information about that, but i think it's limited to chrome. If you could add a little bit more context on what you are trying to do, we could try to find another solution.

Comment: Do you mean the javascript function working on IE to check free RAM memory? I think you could only achieve this using Chrome. Using [`performance.memory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/memory) mentioned in the above comment. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913150/javascript-ram-memory-usage). You could provide a minimal sample to show what you have achieved so that we can understand your need more clearly.

Comment: There is this new properties added to navigator object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory
But it's not available in all the browsers and may take years to come.