# Detect memory exhaustion in the browser before it crashes

Tags: javascript, events, memory, browser, low-memory

When a JavaScript client application uses too much memory, the browser will either crash or throw an exception that can't be recovered from or swap like it's the 80s.

**Do browsers signal that they almost reached the available memory limit for a tab?**

Ideally, I'd love to be able to catch an event that I can intercept in JavaScript when the browser is running low on memory in order to automatically fall back to a light version of the application or tell my users to go buy a new computer / phone.

I know Chrome Performance Tools allow imprecise querying of the used memory, which is a first step, but probably not enough to detect memory limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no cross-browser way to detect this unfortunately. This is discussed a little bit in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860215/223486).

There is `window.performance.memory` but that is [only available in Chrome](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory).

I'm not aware of any really good workarounds for this either. You could perhaps check for old browsers or browsers that don't have particular features (["feature detection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(web_development))) and suggest that users with older browsers use your "light" version, since those are the people most likely to have low-powered devices.

Another possibility would be to see how long some particular operations take, and if they take too long then recommend the light version. Again a very blunt solution.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my intuition. I'll mark this as answered, hoping I'll be able to switch to a better answer at some point in the future !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in speed of browser.

It doesn't show memory very correctly to prevent fingerprinting exactnes.

So, http://thisbeautiful.w3spaces.com/notbad.htm contains code to loop with an interval like this:

JavaScript:

```js
momentum=Date.now();for(itr=1;itr<770;itr++){};momentumTwo=Date.now()-momentum;if(momentumTwo>3){ //take action
     } //and every second if you wrap in into an interval
```

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516931/how-to-get-cpu-usage-in-javascript/73316065#73316065) to get example.

**Summary**:the code sees how long it takes to loop things and, if crash, take action.

Answer (score -1):

Using a program that monitors the browser system should be a better solution, as browsers themselves are not fully able do such a thing.