# How to get CPU usage in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to get the CPU(s) usage in JavaScript on the browser?

Comment: The link that suggest the duplication does not exist any more

Comment: There is a way to check it in Node.js and request it in Javascript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From what I have gathered, the most you can find out natively in the browser about JS CPU stats, is the **amount of CPU cores** the client is using. Insert this in your JS file:

```
console.log(navigator.hardwareConcurrency)
```

You can then check that in the Chrome Dev Tools console.

However, **you can calculate the CPU load using Node.js**.  [Here is a step-by-step on that.](https://gist.github.com/bag-man/5570809)

The answer on this page may also be of help in your dilemma: [Javascript- Dynamically monitor CPU/memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530680/javascript-dynamically-monitor-cpu-memory-usage)

Comment: Is there any way to get only the CPUs that are being used by a node process? 
os.cpus() gets all the CPUs in a system, doesn't it?

Comment: It returns me 4?

Comment: Does not work on firefox and the information given is almost unusable, no link to CPU usage at all, only number of CPUs, which can mean everything

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, no. BUT... and this is a big BUT, if your application is an SPA you could consider deploying it via Electron.

If you did this you could then access the CPU usage: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/cpu-usage

For you it's not a big leap to move from the web to Electron. But for your users it's a big change from accessing something in the browser to downloading an app. However, if this is a very important feature of your app/service then it might be worth it...

Comment: Even if your app is not targeting Electron, it's possible to deploy any SPA to Electron and you can monitor the CPU usage there.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you may be looking for is measuring the current CPU intensitivity.

```js
if((new Date()).getDay()==6){}else{

work = new Worker("data:text/javascript,setInterval(` dl=Date.now();for(itr=1;itr<1000;itr++){};dl=Date.now()-dl;postMessage(dl);`,1000);");

work.onmessage = (evt)=>{
     console.info(12 - evt.data+(' point'+((new Intl.PluralRules(navigator.language)).select(12-evt.data)=='one'?'':'s')))
       };
   }
```

Workers would measure the CPU speed of looping.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more interesting and interactive example of how you might measure CPU performance with Javascript.

---

The following example uses a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to record the number of loop cycles performed. This data can be used as a relative benchmark of CPU performance.

Do note that this may not result in the best user experience, since it does take up a significant portion of the user's CPU.

```js
const blob = new Blob(
  [
    `let time = performance.now()
           let iterations = 0;
           while(true){
                iterations++;
                let now = performance.now()
                if(now - time > 100){
                    postMessage(iterations)
                    time = performance.now()
                    iterations = 0
                }
           }`,
  ], {
    type: "text/javascript"
  }
);

const processWorker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

const performanceData = [];

processWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
  performanceData.push(+e.data);
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = performanceData.slice(-50);
  chart.update();
};

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: Array(50).fill(""),
    datasets: [{
      data: performanceData,
      borderColor: "#0f796b",
      fill: !0,
      fillColor: "#96c4be",
      tension: 10,
      cubicInterpolationMode: "monotone"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 0,
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: !1
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: !1
      }
    },
    animation: {},
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px; width: 400px">
  <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.0.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On nodeJS there is a library : [systeminformation](https://systeminformation.io/) [npm systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) This library provides system information like CPU, Memory, battery, and more, on several OS: Windows, Linux, Sun, and Mac.
It requires Node, I do not think it would work on webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question says:

> on the browser

Maybe it's helpful to know that Microsoft Edge(not sure if it's exclusive) has a tab called "[Performance Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/performance-monitor/performance-monitor-tool)" inside it's dev tools. It shows CPU Usage, JS Heap size, etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34570698)

Comment: @MCGRAW I thought I was doing this by mentioning the tab's existence inside the dev tools. I'm not sure what else I would need to provide, the link is just a more extensive explanation of what the performance monitor does. The link changing wouldn't change the answer. Could you please clarify what I need to add or change to give a complete answer?