# How can I programatically test OCTANE score in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

Referring to https://chromium.github.io/octane/

How can my js know, at run time, the performance of its environment?

Interactively, I use Octane, but via code I am fine with any reasonable proxy for that value. IOW how can I measure js performance at run time from my js ?

Comment: Are you asking how you can do what Octane does, or are you asking how you can us JS to connect to Octane?

Comment: @Ajaypayne  OP enhanced, thanks!

Comment: If you are looking to do what Octane does and run some tests against different things, I looked at the script Octane uses and they are almost all free software, so just include the ones that you want.

Comment: @Ajaypayne is there a simple single call I can make that returns a useful cpu performance metric?

Comment: Ah, okay. There is this question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516931/how-to-get-cpu-usage-in-javascript that may help you.

Comment: @Ajaypayne No, that is related to number of CPUs, not js performance