# Getting downloaded size of HTML+JS page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML+JS+CSS page with known size.

During page load, I wanna know how much bytes have been downloaded by browser. Is there any way?

(In fact, I want to know that just to show user a meaningful progress bar. i.e. progress bar advances by amount of bytes being downloaded.)
Thanks

Comment: There is in modern browsers if you load by XHR, otherwise not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Maybe try using [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)?

Comment: You could download a small "loader" page which uses XHR to load the actual page.

Comment: I'm aware of Pace.js and other similar JS libraries. But my question is WHEN to increment progress bar. My web page is relatively large and i wanna show user a meaningful MESSAGE (by progress bar) to wait.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I send pages size to client with Json object. Then in the client measure memory usages. By minus these sizes, you can estimate downloaded size.

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page

Answer (score -1):

Use [`fakeLoader.js`](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/fakeLoader.js/) which need jQuery Library.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fakeloader").fakeLoader({
        timeToHide: 1200,
        bgColor: "#2ecc71",
        spinner: "spinner1"
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fakeLoader.css">
<div id="fakeLoader"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://joaopereirawd.github.io/fakeLoader.js/demo/js/fakeLoader.min.js"></script>
```

Demo URL: http://joaopereirawd.github.io/fakeLoader.js/demo/demo1.html

Comment: And how will you show a meaningful progress bar with this?

Comment: BTW, I believe that "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" is preferred over the less accurate "self executing function".  See http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: In plain JS, this will be solution. in jQuery, we have document.ready !

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderO'Mara -- I don't see how this shows a loading progress bar.

Comment: But how will you know what values to set on the progress bar? They mentioned using known files sizes, but asked how they could determine the current download progress.

Comment: The progress bar would need to be updated by the page and brings the OP back to the initial question of how to get updates on the status of a page load. The OP wasn't asking how to run code when the page is loaded but to get status updates during page load so he can provide a status bar.

Comment: My Earlier answer was an idea not the total solution. right now shared the jQuery Plugin which does everything what is required.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, Let us know your views