# Get current memory usage of HTML document?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory, benchmarking

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the current memory usage of a specific page? I am working on a little DOM-render experiment where I'm rendering 100 000+ DOM-elements and want to be able to show the memory usage of the application before rendering the DOM as well as after completion to se the difference. Any JS-library or something that will help me do that? Preferably with Chrome, FF and IE support.

The application is constructed with HTML and JS

Thanks

Comment: Internet explorer: F12 Memory profiler (from on version IE11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery or javascript to find memory usage of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page)

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page) from galambalazs

Unfortunately, right now this is still a Chrome only feature (a non-standard extension of window.performance).

`window.performance.memory`

Browser support: Chrome 6+

You could also [look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now):

`The Performance.now()`

> A method returns a DOMHighResTimeStamp, measured in milliseconds, accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond.

This is more widely supported

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. As far as I know from read about window.performance.memory it doesn't add DOM-nodes into the equation? When I try to run it before and after rendering DOM i get the same memory usage.

Comment: You could use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). See [my example here](https://jsfiddle.net/5squvgLv/1/). I hope this helps.