# script how to show loading time and memory usage web page in footer library jquery and angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

how to show loading time and memory usage web page in footer with library jquery and angularjs ? ...

I've finished one issue, to show loading time at the library jquery, the following code themselves:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
before = (new Date()).getTime();
function pageload()
{
    var after = (new Date()).getTime();
    var sec = (after-before)/1000;
    var p = document.getElementById("loadingtime");
    p.innerHTML = "Load In : " + sec + " seconds";  
}
 window.onload = function () 
    { 
        pageload();
    }
</script>
```

and I write `<p id = "loadingtime">` in footer web page. this code from : 
http://nuelcoding.blogspot.co.id/2016/01/php-javascript-web-page-load-time.html

but, for angularjs I can not yet, anyone can help? ...

and for memory usage I can not at all, either in angularjs or jquery? ...

view eventually will be like this:

Load In: 0.015 seconds | Memory: ... MB

anyone can help, thanks for the answer.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript

Comment: Use the `Date` object

Answer (score 2):

For the memory you may find your answer here : [jQuery or javascript to find memory usage of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page)

```
  window.performance.memory
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object seems like the way to go From Mozilla [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

**Calculating elapsed time**

```
// using Date objects
var start = Date.now();

// the event to time goes here:
doSomethingForALongTime();
var end = Date.now();
var elapsed = end - start; // elapsed time in milliseconds
```

Often times `Performance.now()`, can be even better. [Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

For memory `window.performance.memory`, seems like a good benchmark as @simo said