# Java Script - Memory Usage

Tags: javascript, memory

I need the information about usage of memory during executing of all scripts on the page and for all script separately, in bytes. Is there this information in web developer tool?

Comment: Did you really not consider [Googling this](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+profile+memory+usage&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS761US761&oq=chrome+profile+memory&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.7191j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery or javascript to find memory usage of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530228/jquery-or-javascript-to-find-memory-usage-of-page)

Comment: But I know this thread and I used window.performance.memory but this result is not helpful for me and yes, I've googled it but I didn't have solution that satisfied me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best memory analysis tool I've seen is Profiles tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

Click "Start" button, perform some page actions, the click the "Stop" button for metrics and which parts of your code is taking the most execution time

Comment: Ok, thank you but unfortunately execution time is all right, they are short.