# Getting an openCV JS error after running the code for longer time

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement beautification in JS using opencv JS but after running for a minute, an error is logged in the console. Can someone please explain why is this happening? Is it related to openCV or is it a memory issue?
Here is my code.

```
let video = document.getElementById("videoInput"); // video is the id of video tag
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOutput');

let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
video.width = 640;
video.height = 480;
navigator.mediaDevices
.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
.then(function(stream) {
video.srcObject = stream;
video.play();

const FPS = 30;
function processVideo() {
  let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let img = new cv.Mat();
  let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
  
  let blur = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let hpf1 = new cv.Mat();
  let hpf = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
    
  let skinArea = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
  let begin = Date.now();
  cap.read(src);
  img=src
  cv.GaussianBlur(img, blur, new cv.Size(15, 15), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
  cv.GaussianBlur(img, hpf1, new cv.Size(3, 3), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)

  cv.subtract(img,hpf1,hpf1)
  let minRange = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), [120, 80, 60, 0]);
  let maxRange = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), [255, 190, 120, 255]);
  cv.inRange(img, minRange, maxRange, skinArea);
  
  maxRange.delete()
  minRange.delete()

  let mat_1 = new cv.Mat();
  cv.imshow("canvasOutput1", skinArea);

  mat_1 = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, cv.CV_8UC1,new cv.Scalar(1,1,1))
  let blur_hpf= new cv.Mat();
  cv.add(blur,hpf1,blur_hpf)
  hpf1.delete()
  blur.delete()
  let blurred = new cv.Mat(),background = new cv.Mat();

  let ones = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, cv.CV_8UC1, new cv.Scalar(1));

  cv.min(skinArea, ones, skinArea)
  ones.delete()
  cv.subtract(mat_1, skinArea,blurred)
  cv.cvtColor(skinArea, skinArea, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
  cv.cvtColor(blurred, blurred, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);

  cv.multiply(skinArea,blur_hpf,skinArea)

  let final_out = new cv.Mat()
  if(blurred == undefined){
    background = img
    final_out = img
  }
  else if(blurred == undefined || img == undefined){
    console.log("not image")
  }
  else{
  cv.multiply(blurred,img,background)
  cv.add(skinArea,background,final_out)
  }
  
  background.delete()
  blurred.delete()
  skinArea.delete()
  let kernel = cv.matFromArray(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1, [0.110, 0.160, 0.07,0.145, 0.143, 0.12,0.150, 0.150, 0.09]);
  cv.filter2D(final_out, final_out, -1, kernel);
  
  cv.imshow("canvasOutput", final_out);
  
  src.delete()
  final_out.delete()
          
  let delay = 100/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
  setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
}
// schedule first one.
setTimeout(processVideo, 0);});
```

It is giving error in cv multiply after the code has run correctly for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

The script crashes after long execution time due to **memory leaks**.

- Execute `cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);` only once before the starting `processVideo()`.
  When working with video, we don't suppose to create new `VideoCapture` object multiple times, and delete it multiple times, because `cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video)` supposes to open a new video stream (it may not be the case in your specific example).
  Create the `VideoCapture` object once, and use it inside `processVideo()` multiple times.
- Make sure do delete **all** the `cv.Mat` objects inside `processVideo()`.
  Consider creating the `cv.Mat` objects before `processVideo()` instead of executing `new` and `delete` multiple times - it's safer, and more efficient.

In case you intend to add a stop function, you may execute `cap.release()` and `cap.delete()` in the stop function.

---

Modified (part) code sample:

```
let video = document.getElementById("videoInput"); // video is the id of video tag
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video); // Create VideoCapture object once before starting processVideo()

const FPS = 30;
function processVideo() {
  let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  //let img = new cv.Mat();
  //let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

  let blur = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let hpf1 = new cv.Mat();
  //let hpf = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);

  let skinArea = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
  let begin = Date.now();
  cap.read(src);
  //img=src
  let img = src;

  cv.GaussianBlur(img, blur, new cv.Size(15, 15), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
  cv.GaussianBlur(img, hpf1, new cv.Size(3, 3), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)

  cv.subtract(img,hpf1,hpf1)
  let minRange = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), [120, 80, 60, 0]);
  let maxRange = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), [255, 190, 120, 255]);
  cv.inRange(img, minRange, maxRange, skinArea);

  maxRange.delete()
  minRange.delete()

  //let mat_1 = new cv.Mat();
  cv.imshow("canvasOutput1", skinArea);

  let mat_1 = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, cv.CV_8UC1,new cv.Scalar(1,1,1))
  let blur_hpf= new cv.Mat();
  cv.add(blur,hpf1,blur_hpf)
  hpf1.delete()
  blur.delete()
  let blurred = new cv.Mat(),background = new cv.Mat();

  let ones = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, cv.CV_8UC1, new cv.Scalar(1));

  cv.min(skinArea, ones, skinArea)
  ones.delete()
  cv.subtract(mat_1, skinArea,blurred)
  cv.cvtColor(skinArea, skinArea, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
  cv.cvtColor(blurred, blurred, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);

  cv.multiply(skinArea,blur_hpf,skinArea)

  let final_out = new cv.Mat()
  if(blurred == undefined){
    background = img
    final_out = img
  }
  else if(blurred == undefined || img == undefined){
    console.log("not image")
  }
  else{
    cv.multiply(blurred,img,background)
    cv.add(skinArea,background,final_out)
  }

  background.delete()
  blurred.delete()
  skinArea.delete()
  let kernel = cv.matFromArray(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1, [0.110, 0.160, 0.07,0.145, 0.143, 0.12,0.150, 0.150, 0.09]);
  cv.filter2D(final_out, final_out, -1, kernel);

  cv.imshow("canvasOutput", final_out);

  src.delete()
  final_out.delete()
  mat_1.delete()
  blur_hpf.delete()

  let delay = 100/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
  setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
};

// schedule the first one.
setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
```

---

### Update:

Monitoring memory usage:

One way to monitor the memory usage is getting the use head size before start executing `onVideoStarted()`, getting the size at the end of `onVideoStarted()`, compute the delta, and print it to the log periodically.

According to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860215/4926757), we may use `window.performance.memory` in Chrome (only) browser.

For getting used heap size we may execute:

```
const heapUsed = window.performance.memory['usedJSHeapSize'];
```

---

- Execute the following code before `onVideoStarted()`:

  ```
   const memUsedBefore = window.performance.memory['usedJSHeapSize']; //Used memory before executing processVideo (in bytes)
  ```
- Execute the following code before the end of `onVideoStarted()`:

  ```
   const additionalMemUsed = window.performance.memory['usedJSHeapSize'] - memUsedBefore;
   console.log(`Additional mem used: ${Math.round(additionalMemUsed/(1024*1024))} MB`);
  ```

The used memory supposed to go up and down.
In case the value keeps raising along time, there is a "memory leak".

---

Code sample (relevant part):

```
const FPS = 30;
const memUsedBefore = window.performance.memory['usedJSHeapSize']; //Used memory before executing processVideo (in bytes)

function processVideo() {
  let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  //let img = new cv.Mat();
  //let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

  let blur = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let hpf1 = new cv.Mat();
  //let hpf = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);

  let skinArea = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
  let begin = Date.now();
  cap.read(src);
  //img=src
  let img = src;

  cv.GaussianBlur(img, blur, new cv.Size(15, 15), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
  cv.GaussianBlur(img, hpf1, new cv.Size(3, 3), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)

  cv.subtract(img,hpf1,hpf1)
  let minRange = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), [120, 80, 60, 0]);
  let maxRange = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), [255, 190, 120, 255]);
  cv.inRange(img, minRange, maxRange, skinArea);

  maxRange.delete()
  minRange.delete()

  //let mat_1 = new cv.Mat();
  cv.imshow("canvasOutput1", skinArea);

  let mat_1 = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, cv.CV_8UC1,new cv.Scalar(1,1,1))
  let blur_hpf= new cv.Mat();
  cv.add(blur,hpf1,blur_hpf)
  hpf1.delete()
  blur.delete()
  let blurred = new cv.Mat(),background = new cv.Mat();

  let ones = new cv.Mat(img.rows, img.cols, cv.CV_8UC1, new cv.Scalar(1));

  cv.min(skinArea, ones, skinArea)
  ones.delete()
  cv.subtract(mat_1, skinArea,blurred)
  cv.cvtColor(skinArea, skinArea, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
  cv.cvtColor(blurred, blurred, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);

  cv.multiply(skinArea,blur_hpf,skinArea)

  let final_out = new cv.Mat()
  if(blurred == undefined){
    background = img
    final_out = img
  }
  else if(blurred == undefined || img == undefined){
    console.log("not image")
  }
  else{
    cv.multiply(blurred,img,background)
    cv.add(skinArea,background,final_out)
  }

  background.delete()
  blurred.delete()
  skinArea.delete()
  let kernel = cv.matFromArray(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1, [0.110, 0.160, 0.07,0.145, 0.143, 0.12,0.150, 0.150, 0.09]);
  cv.filter2D(final_out, final_out, -1, kernel);

  cv.imshow("canvasOutput", final_out);

  src.delete()
  final_out.delete()
  mat_1.delete()
  blur_hpf.delete()

  let delay = 100/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);

  //Subtract memUsedBefore from the current allocated heap size
  const additionalMemUsed = window.performance.memory['usedJSHeapSize'] - memUsedBefore;
  console.log(`Additional mem used: ${Math.round(additionalMemUsed/(1024*1024))} MB`); //Print to log - should be around zero.

  setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
};
```

Comment: I tried this but still facing the same issue. Also if I delete img mat, it is giving binding error.

Comment: Compare your code with the code sample in my answer. There is no need to delete a reference to an object. Using Windows Task Manager, it's simple to see the memory usage keeps rising (I didn't try other OS).

Comment: I updated my answer with memory usage monitoring example. In case the issue is not a "memory leak", you may post the HTML, and other dependencies. I used the example from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/dd/d00/tutorial_js_video_display.html), for testing. It's working in my machine (with my Webcam)...